# Conditional graphing in a function within lapply() in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, lapply

My sample dataframe `df` is as follows

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
          var1 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
          var2 = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001),
          var3 = c(1:8))
```

My goal is to plot `var2` by `var3` in a line graph using `ggplot2`, but I want a separate plot for each unique `ID` value.  I have used the following code, which works well.

```
lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x)
{
  ggplot(x, aes(var2, var3)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
})
```

Next I would like to make all points for values where `var3` is greater than 4 to be filled in white.  I tried the following code but it returns the error "In if (df$var3 > 4) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used."

```
plot_list<- lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x)
{
  ggplot(x, aes(var2, var3)) +
    geom_line() +
    if(df$var3 > 4) {
      geom_point(fill = "white")
    } else{
      geom_point(fill = "black")
    }
})
```

What am I doing wrong here and is there any way I can include a conditional statement in my function?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want a separate plot for each `ID`, have you considered either of the `facet_*` functions?

Comment: As an aside: For the `fill` argument to have an effect here you need set the `shape` to 21 - 25. See http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/

Comment: Regarding the error, use `ifelse`, which is vectorized: `... + geom_line() + geom_point(fill = ifelse(x[["var3"]] > 4, "white", "black"), shape = 21)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. Store the color in a new variable, enable the `color` option in `aes()` and then use `scale_color_identity()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
                 var1 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                 var2 = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001),
                 var3 = c(1:8))
#Create color var
df$Color <- ifelse(df$var3>4,'white','black')
#Plot
lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x)
{
  ggplot(x, aes(x=var2,y=var3,color=Color)) +
    geom_line(color='black') +
    geom_point()+
    scale_color_identity()
})
```

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or you can be more practical and use `fill` and `shape=21` as mentioned by **@markus**:

```
#Plot 2
lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x)
{
  ggplot(x, aes(x=var2,y=var3,fill=Color)) +
    geom_line(color='black') +
    geom_point(shape=21)+
    scale_fill_identity()
})
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or being more advanced as **@r2evans** and avoid the messy lapply using facets:

```
#Plot 3
ggplot(df, aes(x=var2,y=var3,fill=Color)) +
  geom_line(color='black') +
  geom_point(shape=21)+
  scale_fill_identity()+
  facet_wrap(.~ID,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you everyone.  I specifically  need to save each plot separately which is why I used `lapply()` instead of `facet_wrap()`.  I haven't used `scale_xx()` series yet and this will be very useful in the future.